# MessageHandler for Julia

Tags: c, rabbitmq, activemq-classic, julia, message-handlers

I'm looking for a message handler for Julia, because I want to integrate it in a bigger project with other services. The other services are using RabbitMQ, but I have not been able to find any RabbitMQ or ActiveMQ drivers for Julia.

Is anyone aware of a message handler driver for Julia or should I just start implementing it on my own?

**[UPDATE]**

I just noticed that Julia is able to call C and Fortran code, so I thought perhaps I could use the RabbitMQ driver for C.

What do you think about this idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of one but have only done a cursory search. There are many Julia libraries which simply wrap an existing and well-understood C API. While getting the package build and install correct this way can be slightly tricky, it saves re-implementing complex protocols. There doesn't seem to be much dogma in the community about trying to make 'pure Julia' packages where there's no clear benefit.

Comment: But do you think that the `C driver` will work fine in Julia?

Comment: I don't know anything about the RabbitMQ drivers, but Julia has been built to make C interop very simple. Try it out!